# Insert an array and show value in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am using checkboxes to see if a user wants "Breakfast,Dinner and Supper"

This is my code for that

```
<div id="checkboxesFood">
                <p>Please select if you want breakfast, dinner and supper</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="food" name="foodboxes[]" value="Breakfast"/>Breakfast
                <input type="checkbox" class="food" style="margin:0 0 0 19%;" name="foodboxes[]" value="Dinner"/>Dinner
                <input type="checkbox" class="food" style="margin:0 0 0 19%;" name="foodboxes[]" value="Supper"/>Supper
            </div>
```

I'm using PHP to connect to a DB and store the value there.

This is my PHP code

```
$username = $_POST['userName']; //Username
$view = $_POST['roomChoice'];   //View Of Room
$paymentMethod = $_POST['payment']; //How user want's to pay
$selectedFood = $_POST['foodboxes'];    //Food they have selected(Breakfast, Dinner or Supper)
//$foodData = array($selectedFood);
$con = new mysqli('localhost','username','mypw','DB');

if($con->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " .$con->connect_error);
}
//$implodedData = implode(",",$foodData);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Hotellbokning(Name,Room,Food,Payment) VALUES('$username','$view','$implodedData','$paymentMethod')";


if($con->query($sql) == true){
    echo "You did it John!";
}
else{
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br/>" .$con->error;
}
```

Just ignore the variables that is not an issue. When I insert this array `$selectedFood` into my DB, I recieve the value "Array" on my Food-field.

Is there a way to see the value of this array(the three values Breakfast,Dinner and Supper) in PhpMyAdmin, or is it only possible to echo them out from my DB?

P.S. I tried using implode but it didn't work. I've also tried `$foodData = array($selectedFood)` But it didn't work either.

Comment: If this is for school assignment, I would highly recommend fixing your SQL injection vulnerability. If I were the teacher, I would automatically fail someone for that. Perhaps consider prepared statements with parametrized values.

Comment: Yes, and I did that for another assignment. I just wanted to know if you could show a array in PhpMyAdmin, and I got the answer I wanted for it. Good thing that you aren't my teacher then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're imploding the wrong thing. `$selectedFood` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in another array. So it should be:

```
$implodedData = implode(',', $selectedFood);
```

Then you can store `$implodedData` in the database.

However, putting comma-separated lists in a database is generally poor design. You should use a relation table with a separate row for each item.

Comment: Yeah I know this is poor design, This is just for a school-assignment. I don't think it's required either, I was just wondering if it's possible, and if, then how?

Comment: Oh look at that. It worked with how you did it. Thanks!